# snap mjpg-streamer-2 paralell install fails with V4L interface: Permission denied

Tags: server, permissions

My computer in the shop has two ubs cameras attached and working fine.  Now I am trying to use mjpg-streamer to send both cameras feed to zoneminder on a second computer in the house.
I have two installs of snap mjpg-streamer mjpg-streamer_exper the original one can send either of the streams (video0 and video2) and zoneminder displays them.
The second install fails with a syslog message that ERROR opening V4L interface: Permission denied  mjpg-streamer_exper.mjpg-streamer-service[10960]:  Init v4L2 failed !! exit fatal
init_VideoIn failed  snap.mjpg-streamer_exper.mjpg-streamer-service.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.mjpg-streamer_exper.mjpg-streamer-service" name="/dev/video2" pid=10960 comm="mjpg_streamer" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Not sure why apparmor is denying it?

Not sure running parallel installs is the best way to handle this?

Thanks
Jim